# Page Not Found when submitting edited answer

Tags: bug, status-norepro, editing

I'm trying to edit [this answer](//superuser.com/questions/9118/any-recommendations-on-a-nas-for-a-home-super-user/9186#9186) of mine over on SuperUser, but when I save the edits, I get redirected to a SU Page Not Found page. Some notes:

- My edit is just adding a link to the page (and describing the edit in the Edit Summary). (I've tried just adding some basic text instead of a link -- same result.)
- I've tried this edit a number of times, always with the same result.
- I've been able to make edits to other questions without any problems.

Here's what I'm seeing:

*removed broken image*

**UPDATE: And now it's working. I'm not aware of anything that's changed, other than making successful edits to a few other pages in the mean time.**

Comment: Any additional tags I should add now that it's working for me? Still seems like this might have been an actual problem.

Comment: +1 for google chrome :p

Answer (score 2):

The page shows up fine for me. I was going to say that if you are seeing Page Not Found that it was probably deleted, but that question you are linking to is open and available.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your cookies got trashed somehow along the way? Not sure, no other reports of this or known issues.